# Prevent user from inputting letters

Tags: python

The user here will input a 10 digit long code:

```
code = input("enter a 10 digit long code")
while len(code) != 10:
    code = input("your code wasn't 10 digits long. input it again.")
```

Now, what would I do to do the same thing but when the user inputs letters instead of numbers? I tried to use `int` and `ValueError`, as advised by other users when others posted a similar question to this, but I got an error when I ran the code. Thanks

Comment: please add your updated code

Comment: `while len(code) != 10 or not code.isdigit():`